# vscode key-binding notworking

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I try to remap "$" to "L" in vscode vim so that I can jump quickly to the end of the line. I am trying using the following jason data.

[image]

However, vscode keep giving me the following feedback:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{ "before": ["$"], "after": ["L"] }` to make `$` behave as `L`?

Comment: You are right, thank you!